Add a space before and after
When I write a reaction with the command \begin{reaction*} \end{reaction] from the chemmacro package, the space (if it exists) before and after the equal sign is very small which, I find, limits the readability of the equation.

Is there any way to improve this?
thanks
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824



\begin{document}

Le couple associé est \ch{AgCl \sld{} / Ag \sld{}}, la demi-équation s'écrit
\begin{reaction*}
AgCl \sld{} + e\mch{} = Ag \sld{} + Cl\mch{}
\end{reaction*}


\end{document}


By default, chemmacros use chemformula for the formulas. The chemformula manual, section 9 Arrows, specifies that the equal sign used for  stoichiometric equations must be enter with ==.
Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

Le couple associé est \ch{AgCl \sld{} / Ag \sld{}}, la demi-équation s'écrit
\begin{reaction*}
AgCl \sld{} + e\mch{} == Ag \sld{} + Cl\mch{}
\end{reaction*}

\end{document}


